# Why does yielding to lambda splat array arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lambda, yield

In Ruby, calling a `lambda` with the wrong number of arguments results in an `ArgumentError`:

```
l = lambda { |a, b| p a: a, b: b }
l.call(1, 2) 
# {:a=>1, :b=>2}

l.call(1)
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
```

Passing an array instead doesn't work either: (because an array is just a single object, right?)

```
l.call([3, 4])
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
```

Unless I use a splat (`*`) to convert the array to an argument list, but I didn't.

**But** ... if I call the lambda implicitly via `yield`, something unexpected happens:

```
def yield_to
  yield(1, 2)
  yield([3, 4])
end

yield_to(&l)
# {:a=>1, :b=>2}
# {:a=>3, :b=>4}   <- array as argument list!?
```

What's even more confusing, a lambda derived via `Method#to_proc` does work as expected:

```
def m(a, b)
  p a: a, b: b
end

yield_to(&method(:m))
# {:a=>1, :b=>2}
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `&` does more than just call `#to_proc` so your last example isn't that fair. But I think the key here is that `yield` doesn't invoke `#call`, it executes a *"bare bones"* block. While the `#call` methods checks the arguments and then executes the block.

Comment: It looks like `yield` uses the equivalent of `call(arg)` or `call(*args)` depending on the expected number of parameters. It's hard to find the corresponding documentation, though.

Comment: @ndn I get the same result if I retrieve the proc via `prc = method(:m).to_proc` and call `yield_to(&prc)`. `prc` is a lambda with two required arguments, just like `l`.

Comment: @EricDuminil then the last example should not raise an exception, either.

Comment: Related but IMO not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945533/why-do-ruby-procs-blocks-with-splat-arguments-behave-differently-than-methods-an

Comment: You should write that as an answer and accept it instead. It's nice to have resolution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here, because this is a known bug:

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12705

And it was fixed in Ruby 2.4.1 (thanks @ndn)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously implementation spelunking is the way. Firstly why does `#call` raise exceptions for lambdas with incorrect arguments? [`Proc::call` explicitly checks for lambdas](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/machine/class/proc.cpp#L58-L102).

Now lets trace `yield`. [It's completely separate from `Proc::call`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/proc.c#L3018). [Starts here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm_eval.c#L1071-L1075), [then](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm.c#L1072-L1076), [then](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm.c#L1040-L1042), [then](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/54fa9f9e1378aa7ef925f86ae776f3d6843eeab3/vm_insnhelper.c#L2624) ([`VM_BH_FROM_PROC` just checks that the thing is indeed a proc](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1407e52ba4915ed7f251dec548b5e68f2a5a6a6e/vm_core.h#L1396-L1401)), [then](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm.c#L1028) (due to the [`goto`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm.c#L1042)). I couldn't trace exactly the magic that happens in the second run of the switch, but it only makes sense that it goes through [the `block_handler_type_iseq` case](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm.c#L1029) or exits the switch. Point is, [`invoke_block_from_c_splattable`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm.c#L1021-L1046) is aware of the lambda status of the supposed proc, but it doesn't use it for anything other than to verify that it is indeed a lambda. It doesn't prevent splatting the arguments.

---

As for the why portion - I'm not sure it's even intentional, the fork in the logic for procs is just missing. Lambdas are mainly advertised as method-like ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: _"`invoke_block_from_c_splattable` is aware of the lambda status"_ – it is, but both, `lambda { ... }` and `Method#to_proc` returns procs that are lambas (i.e. have their lambda-flag set). Yet, they are treated differently.

Comment: @Stefan, method procs fall in the [`block_handler_type_ifunc`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm.c#L1034) case, which is different from `block_handler_type_proc`?

Comment: Here's a missing lambda check: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/vm_insnhelper.c#L2435 – I don't understand the whole code but that could explain, why lambdas are treated like ordinary procs.

Answer (score 2):

The differences might come from the way `to_proc` is written: for a simple lambda or proc, it just returns self. For a method, it sets `is_from_method` flag to `true`, and this comes into play when the proc is [invoked in the VM](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/vm.c#L1130-L1143):

```c
if (proc->is_from_method) {
    return vm_invoke_bmethod(th, proc, self, argc, argv, passed_block_handler);
}
else {
    return vm_invoke_proc(th, proc, self, argc, argv, passed_block_handler);
}
```

It looks like if the proc was created from a method, the arguments will be checked.

Comment: Unless you show that lambdas are `if_from_method` (which [doesn't seem to be the case](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/91587f6b63df794db6b4b2ce8f94f78344044ff2/vm.c#L804)), this is just a speculation. Though likely in the right direction.

Comment: @ndn unfortunately, `Proc` doesn't have a `from_method?` method so it cannot be easily shown, but eugen is correct: a proc created via `lamba` doesn't have its `is_from_method` flag set.

Comment: Besides, does anyone know, _why_ it is handled differently?

Comment: @Stefan, I think eugen was saying it is set and that is why we get different results (as opposed with other procs).

Comment: After digging in Ruby's source code for a while, I'm not sure anymore if this really explains it. The mentioned C function `rb_vm_invoke_proc` seems to the one being invoked when calling `Proc#call` and as shown in my examples, `call` works as expected. It's just `yield` that differs.

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the docs, I think it is a bug in Ruby. [Proc class docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Proc.html) explicitly say that:

> The & argument preserves the tricks if a Proc object is given by &
>   argument.

By that docs are saying that the way of handling params should be preserved even when lambda is passed with `&` to a method.

Following code

```
l = lambda { |a, b| p a: a, b: b }

def yield_to(&block)
  yield([3, 4])
  p block.lambda?
end

yield_to(&l)
```

outputs

```
{:a=>3, :b=>4}
true
```

Which is mutually exclusive.

What is interesting, is that this code fails with `ArgumentError`

```
l = lambda { |a, b| p a: a, b: b }

def yield_to(&block)
  block.call([3, 4])
  p block.lambda?
end

yield_to(&l)
```

Comment: It does preserve it if you capture it with `&` and use `#call`. I didn't see the docs saying anything about `yield` behaviour explicitly.

Comment: not sure, but I think it is expected that `yield` and `call` should work the same way with a passed block

Comment: well if that is the expectation, then yes - it is a bug. I was simply pointing out that the resource you provided doesn't document such expectation.

Comment: I've just updated my question, it is a bug and it was already reported.