# Why is `to_ary` called from a double-splatted parameter in a code block?

Tags: ruby, lambda, parameters, codeblocks

It seems that a double-splatted block parameter calls `to_ary` on an object that is passed, which does not happen with lambda parameters and method parameters. This was confirmed as follows.

First, I prepared an object `obj` on which a method `to_ary` is defined, which returns something other than an array (i.e., a string).

```rb
obj = Object.new
def obj.to_ary; "baz" end
```

Then, I passed this `obj` to various constructions that have a double splatted parameter:

```rb
instance_exec(obj){|**foo|}
# >> TypeError: can't convert Object to Array (Object#to_ary gives String)
```

```rb
->(**foo){}.call(obj)
# >> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

```rb
def bar(**foo); end; bar(obj)
# >> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

As can be observed above, only code block tries to convert `obj` to an array by calling a (potential) `to_ary` method.

Why does a double-splatted parameter for a code block behave differently from those for a lambda expression or a method definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have full answers to your questions, but I'll share what I've found out.

### Short version

Procs allow to be called with number of arguments different than defined in the signature. If the argument list doesn't match the definition, `#to_ary` is called to make implicit conversion. Lambdas and methods require number of args matching their signature. No conversions are performed and that's why `#to_ary` is not called.

### Long version

What you describe is a difference between handling params by lambdas (and methods) and procs (and blocks). Take a look at this example:

```rb
obj = Object.new
def obj.to_ary; "baz" end
lambda{|**foo| print foo}.call(obj)   
# >> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
proc{|**foo| print foo}.call(obj)
# >> TypeError: can't convert Object to Array (Object#to_ary gives String)
```

`Proc` doesn't require the same number of args as it defines, and `#to_ary` is called (as you probably know):

> For procs created using `lambda` or `->()`, an error is generated if wrong number of parameters are passed to the proc. For procs created using `Proc.new` or `Kernel.proc`, extra parameters are silently discarded and missing parameters are set to `nil`. ([Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Proc.html))

What is more, `Proc` adjusts passed arguments to fit the signature:

```rb
proc{|head, *tail| print head; print tail}.call([1,2,3])
# >> 1[2, 3]=> nil
```

Sources: [makandra](https://makandracards.com/makandra/20641-careful-when-calling-a-ruby-block-with-an-array), [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945533/why-do-ruby-procs-blocks-with-splat-arguments-behave-differently-than-methods-an).

`#to_ary` is used for this adjustment (and it's reasonable, as `#to_ary` is for implicit conversions):

```rb
obj2 = Class.new{def to_ary; [1,2,3]; end}.new
proc{|head, *tail| print head; print tail}.call(obj2)
# >> 1[2, 3]=> nil
```

It's described in detail in [a ruby tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6039).

You can see that `[1,2,3]` was split to `head=1` and `tail=[2,3]`. It's the same behaviour as in multi assignment:

```rb
head, *tail = [1, 2, 3]
# => [1, 2, 3]
tail
# => [2, 3]
```

As you have noticed, `#to_ary` is also called when when a proc has double-splatted keyword args:

```rb
proc{|head, **tail| print head; print tail}.call(obj2)
# >> 1{}=> nil
proc{|**tail| print tail}.call(obj2)
# >> {}=> nil
```

In the first case, an array of `[1, 2, 3]` returned by `obj2.to_ary` was split to `head=1` and empty tail, as `**tail` wasn't able to match an array of`[2, 3]`.

Lambdas and methods don't have this behaviour. They require strict number of params. There is no implicit conversion, so `#to_ary` is not called.

I think that this difference is implemented in [these two lines](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/547f574b639cd8586568ebb8570c51faf102c313/vm.c#L1096-L1097) of the Ruby soruce:

```c
    opt_pc = vm_yield_setup_args(ec, iseq, argc, sp, passed_block_handler,
(is_lambda ? arg_setup_method : arg_setup_block));
```

and in [this function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d7fdf45a4ae1bcb6fac30a24b025d4f20149ba0a/vm_insnhelper.c#L2895).  I guess `#to_ary` is called somewhere in [vm_callee_setup_block_arg_arg0_splat](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d7fdf45a4ae1bcb6fac30a24b025d4f20149ba0a/vm_insnhelper.c#L2866-L2879), most probably in `RARRAY_AREF`. I would love to read a commentary of this code to understand what happens inside.